# Regex for extracting string with interrogation (?) mark in Python

Tags: python, html, regex

How to extract string (i.e. link with arguments) with "?" in it? When I tried to use :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
html = """
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.somesite.com/wp-content/themes/Dessa/scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js?ver=1.3'></script>
<a href="http://www.somesite.com/hard-circuit-editor-double-layout-design-now/">
"""
print re.findall( r'(href=|src=)"([^"]*)"', html, re.U)
print re.findall( r'(href=|src=)"(.*?)"', html, re.U)
```

string is just overlooked. It would be excellent to separate `?ver=1.3` in third group. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute values are surrounded not only by `"`, but also `'`.

Modification to the regular expression is required:

```
print re.findall( r'''(href=|src=)["']([^"']*)["']''', html, re.U)
```

use `["']` to match either `"` or `'`.

---

**UPDATE**

To get `ver=1.3` part, you'd better to use [`urlparse.urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse) (In Python 3.x, [`urllib.parse.urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse)).

```
>>> import re
>>> import urlparse
>>>
>>> html = """
... <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.somesite.com/wp-content/themes/Dessa/scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js?ver=1.3'></script>
... <a href="http://www.somesite.com/hard-circuit-editor-double-layout-design-now/">
... """
>>> for attrname, value in re.findall(r'''(href=|src=)["']([^"']*)["']''', html, re.U):
...     print value, urlparse.urlparse(value).query
...
http://www.somesite.com/wp-content/themes/Dessa/scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js?ver=1.3 ver=1.3
http://www.somesite.com/hard-circuit-editor-double-layout-design-now/
```

Comment: This works, but when I make it r'''(href=|src=)["']([^"']*)\?(.*?)["']''' to separate third group (after ?) it doesn't recognize other links. Can group be added non mandatory? Could you help, albeit your answer is correct?

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with the character `?` (and I'm not sure why you'd assume it does).

You don't use the character `"` to delimitate the URL, you use the character `'`. Just change the string to :

```
html = """
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://www.somesite.com/wp-content/themes/Dessa/scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js?ver=1.3"></script>
<a href="http://www.somesite.com/hard-circuit-editor-double-layout-design-now/">
"""
```

And it will produce the correct result :

```
>>> print(re.findall( r'(href=|src=)"([^"]*)"', html, re.U))
[('src=', 'http://www.somesite.com/wp-content/themes/Dessa/scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js?ver=1.3'), ('href=', 'http://www.somesite.com/hard-circuit-editor-double-layout-design-now/')]
```

Comment: I didn't use any of " or ' but WordPress generates them. :( Upvote, however.

Comment: The point of my answer was to point out what the problem was, but if you can't change the string, than falsetru's answer is clearly the thing to do here.